# cambiar de posicion un valor de un array

Tags: java, array, bootstrap-switch

ahí va mi pregunta, que no sé no como meterle mano.
Cómo pedir al usuario una posición de array válida y un valor numérico entre 0 y 100 para situarlo en la posición indicada?
Esto sería un case de un switch.
Lo más que he conseguido ha sido esto, pero em coloca siempre el valor en tercera posición:

```
        case 1:
        double num;
        int posi;
        do{
            System.out.print("indique un valor: ");
            num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }while (num <0 || num>100);

        do{
        System.out.print("indique una posicion: ");
        posi = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }while (posi <0 || posi >3);

        posi=num;

        if (posi==0){
            arrayD[0]=posi;
            if (posi==1){
                arrayD[1]=posi;
            }
        }else arrayD[2]=posi;
        System.out.println("\nLos elementos del Array son:\n");
        for (int fila=0; fila<arrayD.length; fila++){
            System.out.print(arrayD[fila]+" \n");
            }
        System.out.print("\n_______________________\n");
        break;
```

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], ¿qué has intentado?, ¿qué errores has obtenido al momento?, ¿qué lenguaje?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tal y como he entendido la pregunta lo que quieres es que el usuario te diga una posición del array y un valor para introducirlo en esa posición. De ser así, te adjunto código

```
double num;
int posi;
do{
   System.out.print("indique un valor: ");
   num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}while (num <0 || num>100);

do{
   System.out.print("indique una posicion: ");
   posi = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}while (posi <0 || posi >3);

//Para acceder a la posición y asignarle ese valor lo único que tienes que hacer es esto
array[posi]=num
```

Espero haber entendido bien la pregunta y que te sirva la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias!!, funciona perfectamente.